# How to process files in a directory in sorted name order by `en_US.utf8`

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to write a bash script that execute the files in a directory in sorted name order. Specifically, the name order is by `en_US.utf8`.

For example, if the dir `/mydir` has the following files:

```
a1.txt
a2.txt
b1.txt
c1.txt
```

I have a function like this:

```
show_content() {
  for f in "$@"; do
  echo $f
  cat $f
  done
}
```

and run it by

```
show_content /mydir/*
```

How can I improve the code to make sure that the `show_content` function execute these files in `/mydir` the name order? How to specify if I want it to follow `en_US.utf8`?

Is there a way to ensure that the `en_US.utf8` is just effective for this bash script? Per @CharlesDuffy and @oguzismail's answer that we can change the setting for `LC_COLLATE` to `en_US.utf8`, but could it be done more "locally" without touching the global settings?

Comment: FYI, you want to `echo "$f"` and `cat "$f"` -- if you leave out the quotes, filenames with spaces will misbehave for the `cat`, and you'll get similar bugs with the `echo`, just (usually, but not always) more-subtle ones. See also [I just assigned a variable; why does `echo $variable` show something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566). And to be _really_ reliable you want `printf '%s\n' "$f"` -- see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803) on [unix.se].

Comment: Anyhow -- what's the value of `LC_COLLATE`? And what's the output of the `locale` command as a whole?

Comment: If `en_US.utf8` is your current locale, you don't need to do anything. Otherwise set `LC_ALL` to `en_US.utf8`.

Comment: Note, btw, that when you run `show_content /mydir/*`, the `/mydir/*` is replaced with a list of filenames **before** `show_content` starts running, so it's too late to change how the glob is expanded -- you can potentially do an additional sorting pass after the expansion, but you can't change how the expansion will occur, because it already finished.

Comment: @IsaIkari you only need `LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! I saw a `LC_COLLATE="C"` in my OS. But is there a way to make the 
en_US.utf8 sorting only effective in this bash script, so I don't need to change any global setting?

Comment: Environment variables are not global. If you set it in the script, it will only apply to the script (and any programs it invokes). You can confirm this with `echo "$LC_COLLATE"` after the script has ended. It will show the original value.

Comment: @IsaIkari, is the `/mydir/*` part of the script, or is it part of what the person starting the script does? If it's the caller who expands the glob, then either that caller needs to have `LC_COLLATE` set, or you need to make your script redo the sorting after it's started. But if the glob is inside the script you can just `export LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8` inside your script and you're good.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's part of the script. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Great! Since it sounds like that comment is what you needed, I'll add an answer w/ the same info.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable `LC_COLLATE` determines which locale's collation rules should be used for sorting.

To make glob expressions *within your script* use `en_US.utf8`, you need only add:

```
export LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8
```

before the glob expression is reached in your script. **This change is local**: It only changes the script itself and subprocesses it runs.

---

By contrast, if you needed to re-sort arguments that were passed in from the outside, doing that reliably (using a `sort` with GNU extensions and a sufficiently modern bash release) might look like:

```
readarray -0 -t args < <(
  printf '%s\0' "$@" | LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 sort -z
)
set -- "${args[@]}"
```